# Why do I get different results while adding noise to a binary images which have different dtypes

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, python

I used the following code to generate images and then add white noise to finally apply morphological operation (opening) to the final image.

**Question ** - why do I get a different result (Result-1) when I add UINT8 image with UINT8 noise

```
img1 = np.zeros((300,600),np.uint8)
cv2.putText(img1, 'ABCD', org=(100,200), fontFace=cv2.FONT_ITALIC, fontScale=5, color=(255,255,255), thickness=25)

img2 = np.zeros((300,600))
cv2.putText(img2, 'ABCD', org=(100,200), fontFace=cv2.FONT_ITALIC, fontScale=5, color=(255,255,255), thickness=25)


noise1 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(300,600), dtype=np.uint8) 
noise2 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(300,600)) 

noise1_img1 = img1+(noise1*255) 
noise2_img2 = img2+(noise2*255) 
noise1_img2 = img2+(noise1*255) 
noise2_img1 = img1+(noise2*255)
```

#### Results :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uint8 dtypes are inherently limited to values between 0 and 255. So, when you add to a value with a value of 255 (in your case, the white text) with another uint8 value, it can't go any higher and will be capped to 255 (ignoring under/overflow).

Now, when you add a uint8 to a higher-bitsized value (float, int, double, whatever), python inherently translates the result to the larger bit number. So, if you have a uint8 image and add int32 noise to it, the result will be able to have values higher than 255 (Which you set your text to). To remove this, you need to either cast the result to uint8:

```
noise2_img2 = (img2+(noise2*255)).astype(np.uint8)
```

or set the value of your font (255,255,255) to be the max value of int32: 2,147,483,647!